# How to create a corpus somthing similar to movie_review using nltk python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, corpus, naivebayes

I running up with an issue, I will just summarize you on what I am trying to accomplish so you get a clear picture to guide me.

I want to create a corpus ***something similar to movie_reviews*** where the movie_review had only to 2 categories, but where as in ***my case I will have multiple categories and sub-categories***.

> For instance:
>
> say I have a corpus as my_corpus in which i wanted to
> create categories such as 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' and 'E'. Each of this
> categories will contain sub-categories such as in 'A' I want to have
> ***sub-category like 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' so on and so forth for all other
> categories as well (B , C, D and E)***. Each of this sub-category will
> again have its own sub-categories like 'a1' might have 'a1.1', 'a1.2'
> etc.. and finally the bottom most (the leaf) ***will contain all the text
> files*** related to that category or sub-category.

My question is

1> How can I create such a corpus, is there anyway to do that, please guide me your response will be a great help, you can also map me to the link which can help me to do this

2> Can I run the ***naivebayes algo or any other algo*** which suites to this case like the one to find the neg and pos in movie_reviews, here in my case as well I need to find the newly asked question relates to which category and its sub-category and so on ?

Kindly help me.

Comment: you could potentially modify the code if you organise it the same way. what does your data look like?

Comment: My data is a text file... The reason I need categories and sub-categories is because I wanted to use it like a nodes, leafs etc structure for some work

Comment: I can't make much sense of part 2) of your question, but I'm pretty sure it's unrelated to the task of defining the corpus reader-- a separate question, in other words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation (and/or source) of [`CategorizedCorpusReader`](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/api.html#CategorizedCorpusReader), e.g. like this:

```
>>> help(nltk.corpus.reader.CategorizedCorpusReader.__init__)
```

This is the base class; you'll actually use the categorized reader that fits your data format. If your files are plain text, that'll be `CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader`. When you create a reader, you can define the categories via a regular expression that extracts the category from the filename, via a file giving the categories, or via a dictionary passed directly to the constructor:

```
- cat_pattern: A regular expression pattern used to find the
  category for each file identifier.  The pattern will be
  applied to each file identifier, and the first matching
  group will be used as the category label for that file.

- cat_map: A dictionary, mapping from file identifiers to
  category labels.

- cat_file: The name of a file that contains the mapping
  from file identifiers to categories.  The argument
  ``cat_delimiter`` can be used to specify a delimiter.
```

There is no direct support for hierarchical categories, but you can arrange that yourself since a file can belong to more than one category. E.g., you would assign the file `donkey.txt` to both `animal` and `mammal`. The nltk's `brown` corpus has files that belong to multiple categories , so you could inspect it for the specifics (it uses the `cat_file` approach).

The nltk's system maps categories to fileids, not to lower-level categories. If you set things up as I suggest, you'll be able to write `mycorpus.words(categories=["A", "B"])` and get the words from all files in categories `Aa1`, `Aa2`, etc. If you want to expose your category hierarchy, you'll have to  code that yourself. (E.g., you could extend the reader class with a method `hierarchy` that just returns the category tree.)

Comment: Thanks a lot alexis, I try this as you say, most probably this approach should help me. Furthermore I will also do some research on the corpus.reader as u told.